# Installing "Emmet plug-in" in Sublime Text Editor

Tags: plugins, sublime-text, html, css

I am using **Sublime Text** code editor and I want to download one of the recommended plug-in for Sublime - **Emmet** for its ability to code *HTML+CSS*
 faster.

[Visit site](https://emmet.io/download/) for more information about Emmet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have **Sublime Text** installed in your PC/Laptop following the below steps will help you to install **Emmet**.

> Visit [here](https://emmet.io/) to find more details on Emmet.
> and to learn how to use [click here](https://docs.emmet.io/).

1. First open **Sublime Text** (type `subl`in Terminal).
2. Than *Click* on **Preferences** in **Menu Bar** and select **Package Control**.

[image: package control]

3. This will open a *text box* as shown, type `install package` hit *enter*.

[image: install package]

4. Now type `emmet` and click on highlighted option.

[image: emmet install]

5. This will start your downloading and installation.
6. You can view the downloading process in *View -> Output Window*.

   > It takes around 5-10 minutes on a stable Internet connection and also asked to *restart* the Sublime Text.